# Quicksight filters in calculated fields

Tags: calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

I have recently started using quicksights sumOver and avgOver functions thinking they behaved like LOD in tableau. That is to say that they exclude a specific filter in the calculation at this visualization level of the data. Using this in Tableau I would traditionally use this to exclude particular filters to give the user a comparison on the difference between say national and state numbers (when they had filtered for a specific state).

Using the over functions in Quicksight does not produce this same result. Unless you only have one (possibly two) filters the over functions actually create sumed, averaged etc. based on partitions. This is not the same as excluding the filter and results in incorrect information for the user when multiple filters are in place. This is because the granularity of the partition becomes smaller every time you add a new dimension into the partitioning. When you then bring this through and visualise it you then are averaging the averages from the partitions and this results in a non-weighted average that is wrong.

My questions is does quicksight have any ability to exclude a particular filter using a function in a calculated field as these over functions do not truly do that?